# Delete column of a NumPy matrix in Python keeping index of all other columns intact

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have the matrix:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

with column indexes 0, 1 and 2.

If I delete column 0 using `SciPy` `delete`, the matrix becomes:

```
[[2 3]
 [5 6]]
```

with column indexes 1, 2 not 0, 1.

Consider the following code:

```
while (np.linalg.norm(r))>0.0001 and (phi!=[]):
     col=phi.shape[1]
    rdotphi0=np.dot(r,phi[:,0])
    while (i in range(1,col)):
        rdotphi=np.dot(r,phi[:,i])
        if(abs(rdotphi)>abs(rdotphi0)):
            max=i
            rdotphi0=rdotphi
        i=i+1
    l.append(max)
    x[max]=rdotphi0
    r=r-(phi[:,max]*rdotphi0)
    phi=scipy.delete(phi,max,1)`
```

I need to append `l` using the original indices, but at the same time I'm in a loop and have to work with new sub-matrices with deleted columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way in which I have done it, is by not deleting the columns; instead, skip them:

```
l=[]
while (np.linalg.norm(r))>0.0001 and (len(l)!=N):
    while i in range(0,col):
        if i in l:
            i+=1
            continue
        else:   
            rdotphi0=np.dot(r,phi[:,i])
            j=i
            m=i
            break
        i+=1    
    print(rdotphi0)
    while i in range(j+1,col):
        if i in l:
            i+=1
            continue
        else:   
            rdotphi=np.dot(r,phi[:,i])
            print(rdotphi)
            if(abs(rdotphi)>abs(rdotphi0)):
                m=i
                rdotphi0=rdotphi
                i+=1        
    print(m)
    l.append(m)     
    x[m]=rdotphi0
    r=r-phi[:,m]*rdotphi0`
```